# Accessing dynamically-created controls inside repeater during postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, repeater, reportviewer

I have an ASP.NET page with a ReportViewer control that displays an SSRS report specified by a GET parameter. I am hiding the ParameterHeader of the ReportViewer and displaying the parameters myself on the ASP.net page using controls like ListBox and CalendarExtender (I am doing this because not everyone is allowed to see everything and I want to have control over the report parameter that selects which parts are displayed).

The number/type of parameters varies between reports so I have an `<asp:Repeater>` databound to the report's parameters (which I get using `ServerReport.GetParameters()`), and I create the drop-down/textbox/calendar controls dynamically and add them to the `ParameterEntryPlaceholder` in `ReportParameterEditRepeater_ItemDataBound`.

```
<table><tr>
    <td>
    <asp:Repeater ID="ReportParameterEditRepeater" OnItemDataBound="ReportParameterEditRepeater_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%#Container.ItemIndex % 4 == 0 ? "<tr>" : "" %>
                <td><b><%#((ReportParameterInfo)Container.DataItem).Prompt %>: </b></td>
                <td><asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ParameterEntryPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder></td>
            <%#Container.ItemIndex % 4 == 3 ? "</tr>" : "<td style='width: 20px;'></td>" %>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ReportRefreshUpdatePanel" ChildrenAsTriggers="True" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="ViewReportBtn" runat="server" OnClick="ViewReportBtn_Click" Text="View Report" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </td>
</tr></table>
```

There is an `<asp:Button>` labelled "View Report" next to my controls, which kicks off a method that is meant to collect the values of all the parameter controls, set them on the ServerReport, and then refresh the report asynchronously.

However, I cannot see the dynamically-created controls during my "View Report" postback - ParameterEntryPlaceholder is empty. I can see them if I re-bind the repeater, but if I do that I lose the user's selections.

TL;DR - how can I access controls that I created / added to the form from code behind during page load, during a postback, without re-binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter what you do, you **need** to re-bind to see the controls. The issue you are having is **when** in the page's lifecycle you are doing the rebinding.

During postback, you need to rebind the dynamically added controls during the OnInit page event. This will allow the ViewState to be restored.

Comment: Doing this with EnableViewState=true on the control, I am able to see the control and access the user (not default) input. Thanks a lot!